# Как запретить повторное выполнение команды?

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

Здравствуйте у меня есть бот анонимного чата
Вот этот код добавляет в очередь пользователя,если он напишет команду  Парень,после этого стоит в очереди или находит сразу собеседника.
Мне нужно,чтобы после того как пользователь ввел команду  Парень ,бот не реагировал на эту команду если пользователь введет еще раз эту команду.

```
        elif message.text == ' Парень':
        user_info = db.get_gender_chat('male')
        chat_two = user_info[0]
        if db.create_chat(message.chat.id, chat_two) == False:
            db.add_queue(message.chat.id, db.get_gender(message.chat.id))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Поиск собеседника', reply_markup = stop_search(),)
        else:
            mess = 'Собеседник найден! Чтобы остановить диалог, напишите /stop'

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, reply_markup = stop_dialog())
            bot.send_message(chat_two, mess, reply_markup = stop_dialog())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаёшь любую переменную которая по умолчанию = 0. И тогда соответственно пишешь
elif message.text == ' Парень' and <переменная>==0:
<переменная>+=1

Comment: И в какую часть кода вставить это все,подскажи

Comment: В самом начале кода можешь объявить переменную к примеру male_done = 0, потом объявляешь её -  global male_done (можно сразу после того как объявил).
там где elif message.text == ' Парень' and male_done==0:
male_done+=1
user_info = db.get_gender_chat('male')

Comment: Не получается ругается на 3 строку моего кода

Comment: name 'male_done' is assigned to before global declaration ошибка,хотя я объявил переменную

Comment: @Beast У вас будет одна переменная для всех пользователей бота. Они будут менять ее значение непредсказуемо.

Comment: дак как мне правильно сделать задуманное ?